# How test-cases should look like

Tags: testing, testcase, black-box-testing

Let us say I want to make a boundary-value test case, I prepare and do the testing but how do I write the test-cases in a nice way? Is there any standardized way of doing this?

Comment: I have always been a fan of naming my test cases `aPopulated[Object name]ShouldNotAllow[Out of bound values]()` it makes it easier (I feel) for others to see what you are testing and it can make it easier for you to keep track of what bounds you remembered to test.  Combining all of our out of bounds tests in a single test function can hide that

Answer (score 0):

For writing test cases for boundary value analysis always take into consideration test data and on boundary less than boundary and greater than boundary.

Let us take an example:
Number range allowed is between 1 to 1000 then, following would be the conditions to be taken in considerations

1) Test cases with test data exactly as the input boundaries of input domain i.e. values 1 and 1000 in our case.

2) Test data with values just below the extreme edges of input domains i.e. values 0 and 999.

3) Test data with values just above the extreme edges of input domain i.e. values 2 and 1001.

Orelse u could also take 0 1 999 1000 1001

Boundary value analysis is often called as a part of stress and negative testing.

Note: There is no hard-and-fast rule to test only one value from each equivalence class you created for input domains. You can select multiple valid and invalid values from each equivalence class according to your needs and previous judgments.